# Как переделать код, чтобы не вызывать функцию inline.

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который нужно переделать, но пока не силен в js. Сейчас код вызывается inline через onclick,  а мне нужно, чтобы он вызывался непосредственно в js с привязкой к классу или id. Спасибо, всем заранее.

Вот пример http://codepen.io/arianalynn/pen/qbmyRZ

```
    var open = false;

    function Drop(n) {
        var i;
        if (open == false) {
            for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
                Drp(i)
            }
            open = true
        } else if (open == true) {
            for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
                Cls(i)
            }
            open = false
        }
    }

    function Drp(n) {
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
        var pos = -1 * window.innerHeight - n * 100;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

        function frame() {
            if (pos >= -10) {
                clearInterval(id);
                elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
            } else {
                pos += 10;
                elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            }
        }
    }

    function Cls(n) {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
        var poss = 0;
        var ids = setInterval(frames, 5);

        function frames() {
            if (poss <= -1 * window.innerHeight) {
                clearInterval(ids);
                elems.style.top = -1 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
            } else {
                poss += -7 - n * 2;
                elems.style.top = poss + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: что вы хотите увидеть на выходе?
что должно быть?

Comment: @L.Vadim Тот же самый результат, что в примере. Просто, код вызывается инлайн, а мне это не совсем подходит, так как вызов функции, нужно расположить перед элементом. Поэтому нужна помощь, чтобы все работало точно также, но вызывать можно было при помощи привязки к id или классу.

Comment: У вас если быстро покликать, элементы перестают слушаться, и бывает что при якобы закрытом состоянии 2 последних остаются в открытом 2 первых в закрытом. *фидбэк

Comment: @Василий Барбашев
Действительно)), есть такое) Это не совсем мой код) Спасибо, за наблюдение. Не думаю, что придется кому-то кликать с такой скоростью.)) А так спасибо)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, а так есть идеи как можно переделать под мои нужды?

Comment: Есть  есть похожие решения, то буду только рад с подобной ситуацией. Думал сделать на CSS,но все это дело потом нужно подружить с адаптивом к тому же все это нужно еще просчитать.

Comment: Сейчас адаптивность === css3, так что не знаю что вы там хотите считать) Тем более это все нативно, и работать будет быстрее чем в js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-icon" id="my-menu" >
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar1"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar2"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('my-menu').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Drop(0);
  e.classList.toggle('hover');
})
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Все работает Супер.

Comment: you welcome :).